# PHP adding items from multidimensional array to navmenu

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, drop-down-menu

I've been tinkering with the idea and concept of making my own module/plugin system for a website. I was having trouble getting the menu (with dropdowns) to form properly, I fixed that with additional loops.

Can anyone take a look and tell me if I could be doing this differently without adding a bunch of loops everywhere?

Test Array

```
<?php
$menu = array (
  array("name","link.php","dropdown","fa-name"),
  array("nothing","#","test",""),
  array("derp","#","ana","fa-derp"),
  array("notta","#","derp","")
);
?>
```

Test Menu

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">TEST</a>
        <ul>
        
        <?php
  foreach($menu as $x)
    if($x[2] == "ana")
        echo '
                <li><a href="' . $x[1] . '">' . $x[0] . '</a></li>
    ';
        ?>
        </ul>
        
    </li>
    
            <?php
  foreach($menu as $x)
    if($x[2] != "ana")
        echo '
                <li><a href="' . $x[1] . '">' . $x[0] . '</a></li>
    ';
        ?>
    
</ul>
```

Comment: If short tags are enabled you don't need to use  `echo`. I usually see templates done as if they were regular HTML with `<?=$var?>` put where they should go. This keeps the output organized and tabbed appropriately and keeps it much more legible.

Comment: I'm less concerned with the way the code looks for now than I am about finding a more resource friendly and efficient way of performing the actions. 

I intend to clean up the code later after I figure out how to make this work a little better.

Comment:  A loop is the process whereby you iterate through an object or array. If you use something like array_map then you're just masking the loop. Given the trivial nature of what you're doing here there will be no difference in performance on even the smallest machine.

Comment: If the echo is the same for all element why not sort the array and then have one loop only?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by have only one loop? Even if I sort the array if I use only one loop it would break the menu by adding multiple dropdowns interlaced with each other.